# Match by whitespace indentation in textmate language grammar

Tags: regex, parsing, grammar, textmate

I have a DSL that I'm trying to write a textmate grammar for, so I can have syntax highlighting (in VS Code rather than textmate, but it uses their grammar)

The DSL represent tree nodes, is whitespace indented, and gets mapped to JSON

Most of it is pretty straightforward, but it has some weird constructs that I'm not sure how to match with the textmate grammar. An example of the DSL is below.

I can match the "tags" and simple scalar type "properties" and the single line "arrays" just fine, but I'm a bit lost on the multiline arrays and objects - I don't know how to stop matching their contents when the indentation changes. I thought I could just stop matching when I hit a known pattern, but its ambiguous between a single item on the last line of the array and a "tag" apart from their indentation level

Is there some way to match these based on indentation alone?

Example DSL file:

```
fooTag
  foo An unquoted string
  bar 42
  baz "42"
  qux true
  barTag
    qux{}
      foo A string called foo on the qux object
      bar null
    foo[] in arrays each space separated token is a separate string "unless quoted"
    bar[]
      some arrays of space separated tokens look like this when it is a long
      list with lots of items
    baz[]
      arrays can be mixed types like this one which contains the number 42 and
      the constants true false and null and the rest of the tokens are all
      strings and even nested arrays and objects as follows
      [] 1 2 3
      []
        indented array of tokens
      {}
        foo 42
        bar "42"
    some
    more
    tags
```

Example JSON output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "fooTag",
    "model": {
      "foo": "An unquoted string",
      "bar": 42,
      "baz": "42",
      "qux": true
    }
  },
  [
    {
      "name": "barTag",
      "model": {
        "qux": {
          "foo": "A string called foo on the qux object",
          "bar": null
        },
        "foo": [
          "each", "space", "separated", "token", "is", "a", "separate",
          "string", "unless quoted"
        ],
        "bar": [
          "some", "arrays", "of", "space", "separated", "tokens", "look",
          "like", "this", "when", "it", "is", "a", "long", "list", "with",
          "lots", "of", "items"
        ],
        "baz": [
          "arrays", "can", "be", "mixed", "types", "like", "this", "one",
          "which", "contains", "the", "number", 42 "and", "the", "constants",
          true, false, "and", null, "and", "the", "rest", "of", "the", "tokens",
          "are", "all", "strings", "and", "even", "nested", "arrays", "and",
          "objects", "as", "follows",
          [ 1, 2, 3 ],
          [ "indented", "array", "of", "tokens" ],
          {
            "foo": 42,
            "bar": "42"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    [
      {
        "name": "some",
        "model": {}
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "more",
        "model": {}
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "name": "tags",
        "model": {}
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: I was looking to the DSL's parser for hints, but it doesn't have to deal with this because in the first pass it builds a preliminary AST from the indentation before it even starts dealing with tokenising each lines' content :(